# LINQ query to turn few items in list as checked

Tags: c#, .net, linq

This is the program along with comments. I have a ListA and ListB. I want to turn ListA's IsChecked = true if it is present in ListB. This is the program:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

List<SomeClass> ListA = new List<SomeClass>
{
    new SomeClass { IsChecked = false, Title = "A" },
    new SomeClass { IsChecked = false, Title = "B" },
    new SomeClass { IsChecked = false, Title = "C" },
    new SomeClass { IsChecked = false, Title = "D" },
    new SomeClass { IsChecked = false, Title = "E" },
    new SomeClass { IsChecked = false, Title = "F" },
};

List<SomeClass> ListB = new List<SomeClass>
{
    new SomeClass { Title = "A" },
    new SomeClass { Title = "D" },
    new SomeClass { Title = "F" },
};

// some linq query at the end of which listA's Item containing Title = "A","D","F" will become true

foreach (var item in ListA)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Title + " " + item.IsChecked); 
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

This is what I came up with:

```
foreach (var item in ListB)
{
    var listAItem = (from itemA in ListA
                     where itemA.Title == item.Title
                     select itemA).First(); //no need for FirstOrDefault() because it is always going to be present

    listAItem.IsChecked = true;
}
```

But this looks very inefficient. Is there any better way of doing this using Linq? I want the solution in LINQ only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a `Join` like this:

```
var itemAsToBeChecked = from itemA in ListA 
                        join itemB in ListB on itemA.Title equals itemB.Title 
                        select itemA;

foreach (var itemA in itemAsToBeChecked)
    itemA.IsChecked = true;
```

I *believe* Microsoft's implementation of [`Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675.aspx) will first create a lookup (`Lookup<,>`) from `Title` to `SomeClass` on `ListB` before enumerating `ListA`, matching each `itemA` with the lookup as it goes. This should be much more efficient than the solution you currently have.

You can also consider using a [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) if you prefer:

```
var titlesToBeChecked = new HashSet<string>(ListB.Select(itemB => itemB.Title));
var itemAsToBeChecked = ListA.Where(itemA => titlesToBeChecked.Contains(itemA.Title));

foreach (var itemA in itemAsToBeChecked)
    itemA.IsChecked = true;
```

Of course, it might make sense here to implement `IEqualityComparer<T>` on your type as others have mentioned, especially if the `Title`-based equality definition is commonly used in your program.

Comment: +1. I liked your solution. What about the Intersect solution that BrokenGlass has provided. Will that too create a lookup? Any idea?

Comment: @Anthony: `Intersect` will work fine if your type had the appropriate equality-implementation, or if you provided an appropriate `IEqualityComparer<T>`. But I don't really like Intersect here because it would be a little confusing for the reader. You normally use `Intersect` when the matching items from either list are "equal" in every possible sense. But you care very much which list the results should come from...(not that the documentation on that method is vague, but it would be strange nevertheless).

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
foreach(var item in ListA.Where( x => ListB.Contains(x)))
  item.IsChecked = true;
```

This would require your class `SomeClass`  to implement `IEquatable<SomeClass>` to compare the Title property:

```
public class SomeClass : IEquatable<SomeClass>
{
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(SomeClass other)
    {
       return this.Title == other.Title;
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can use [`Intersect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355408.aspx) which would require you to provide an `IEqualityComparer`:

```
foreach (var item in ListA.Intersect(ListB, new SomeClassComparer()))
    item.IsChecked = true;

...
public class SomeClassComparer : IEqualityComparer<SomeClass>
{
    public bool Equals(SomeClass x, SomeClass y)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
             return false;
        return x.Title == y.Title;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(SomeClass obj)
    {
        return obj.Title.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution (doesn't require implementation of `IComparable` or `IEquatable`, in case you have no control over that class):

```
foreach (var item in ListA.Where(a => ListB.Any(b => b.Title == a.Title)))
{
    item.IsChecked = true;
}
```

Keep in mind that you'll need this foreach unless you want to rewrite `ListA`. Linq is a query language, not something that should be used to modify an existing list. To use pure Linq hides your intent here. There is probably a way to use a `.Join` or `.Zip` appropriately to return a new `ListA`, but it is always better to modify using traditional constructs.

Answer (score 1):

```
var q = from i1 in listA
        from i2 in listB
        where i1.Title == it2.Title
        select i1;

foreach (var i in q)
{
    i.IsChecked = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used [Enumerable.Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx) operator:

```
public class SomeClass : IEquatable<SomeClass>
{
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(SomeClass other)
    {
        //Check whether the compared object is null.
        if (ReferenceEquals(other, null)) return false;

        //Check whether the compared object references the same data.
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;

        //Check whether SomeClass's properties are equal.
        return Title.Equals(other.Title);
    }

    // If Equals() returns true for a pair of objects 
    // then GetHashCode() must return the same value for these objects.
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        //Get hash code for the Title field if it is not null.
        int hashSomeClassTitle = Title == null ? 0 : Title.GetHashCode();

        //Calculate the hash code for SomeClass.
        return hashSomeClassTitle;
    }
}
```

After implementing `Equals` and `GetHashCode` you're good to go:

```
var intersection = ListA.Intersect(ListB);

foreach (var item in intersection)
{
    item.IsChecked = true;

    Console.WriteLine(item.Title + " " + item.IsChecked);
}
```